# how to redirect from htaccess /en/blog to a folder located at ./blog

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, prestashop-1.6

I have a store in pretashop 1.6 with url [www.example.com/en/](http://www.example.com/en/) in the root of the project I have a folder called blog that contains a wordpress, to view the blog, the url is as follows [www.example.com/blog/](http://www.example.com/blog/), I need it to be [www.example.com/en/blog/](http://www.example.com/en/blog/)

I have tried the following:

- Put the blog in a folder ./en/blog, from htaccess add the 301 redirect from /blog to /en/blog, I have changed in the wordpress database the references from */blog to */en/blog and it works correctly, but the prestashop store does not work, since when entering [www.example.com/en](http://www.example.com/en) throws an access denied error.

I think what I need to do with htaccess is that when I search for /en/blog/ the folder I read is /blog even if the url shows /en/blog/, but I can't know how to do it.

How can I do it? Can you think of an idea?

Thank you very much for your answers

Comment: What does your http server's error log file contain as a result of such requests?

Comment: Also please add your current rewriting rules to the question. When different applications come into each others way this typically is an issue with orders of directives.

Answer (score 0):

based on this [documentation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/)
I put an example of how I think the .htaccess can work, also refresh the permanent links in WordPress and save again.

```
#  BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /en/blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /en/blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

#END WordPress
```